# Scala: overriding def with val

Tags: scala, inheritance

Consider following example:

```
abstract class Item {
  def price: Double
  def description: String
}

class SimpleItem1(override val price: Double, override val description: String) extends Item{}    
class SimpleItem2(val price: Double, val description: String) extends Item{}
```

It compiles successfully and both extended classes have same methods. Are they actually the same? If not - what is the difference? If yes - please explain this to me a little bit, for example: why they decided that 'override' is optional here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `price` and `description` are abstract in `Item`, you are not required to use the `override` modifier. If they had default implementation, you would have to add the `override` modifier.

Thus, in `SimpleItem1`, the modifier is superfluous. There are some circumstances where adding an `override` "just in case" makes sense. For example if you define a trait that you might want to mix-in to a class that has a default implementation.

---

Here is an example, where `override` would make a difference:

```
trait Item0 {
  def price: Int
}

trait Item1 extends Item0 {
  def price = 33
}

trait Item2 extends Item0 {
  override def price = 33
}

object Foo1 extends Item1  // ok
object Foo2 extends Item2  // ok
object Foo3 extends Item0 with Item1  // ok
object Foo4 extends Item2 with Item1  // NOPE!
object Foo4 extends Item1 with Item2  // aha!
```

---

In general you should avoid using `override` where possible.

Comment: Good answer, with exception of the last sentence. There is no advantage in not writing `override`, it helps to make the code much clearer and safer for future additions. Some saved keystrokes are not worth the hindrances (your example is a good example how code should not be written).

Comment: @sschaef - I think it's good design to not work with overloading stuff, I stand by this statement. I _very rarely_ have to use overloading, and I don't feel I am missing anything. There are frameworks, like Swing, which do work with overloading, but in general if you design your classes, you should be able to do without it.

Comment: @0__ - I think what sschaef meant was -"you should write override every time when you are overriding smth. You shouldn't skip this word even if syntax allows you to". And he wrote it because your last sentence is a bit confusing. I personally understood it as: "when you are overriding smth, don't use 'override' word if you can and syntax allows you to". Still I may be wrong here about who meant what :) .

Comment: @GrayR You are not allowed to override anything without the `override` modifier. You can only omit it if you implement an abstract method.

Comment: @0__ lol))). I understand that. I am not sure you understood any of the comments written to you here by me or sschaef. Please just read last sentence of your great answer for a few times and try to think about how it can be misunderstood by other people.